# Why must an EFI partition be at least 100MB?

Tags: boot, uefi

According to [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI), an EFI system partition must be:

> minimum 100Mib. 200MiB recommended.

My EFI partition has been 70MB for a long time, and less than 4MB of it has ever been used. I've never experienced any problems related to the size of my EFI partition.

Why therefore, is the official minimum size 100MB? Does the amount of data stored on EFI partitions vary between systems?

Comment: There's a difference between MB, stated in your headline, and MiB. You can read more here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte. While Windows uses MB, Linux uses the correct MiB in your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [comment on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/partman-efi/+bug/811485/comments/4) explains it all: some boot loaders like ELILO (EFI Linux Boot Loader) require the kernel to reside on the EFI partition while other boot loaders like GRUB2 (used by default by Ubuntu) do not. This is why most Ubuntu user have an almost empty EFI partition. Still the partition needs to be large enough for future needs (if you decide to use a different boot loader).